# Create POJO Class for JSON

Tags: json, pojo

Below is the json object, I need to create the pojos. I had tried couple of things but not able to find anything relevant. Here the key itself is varying/dynamic

```
{
    "ABC" : {
                "values": {
                    "orr": {
                        "data": {
                            "1574065955000": 0.2,
                            "1574066955000": 0.34,
                            "1574067955000": 0.6899
                        }
                    },
                    "cpu": {
                        "data": {
                            "1574065955000": None,
                            "1574067955000": None
                        }
                    }
               }     
    },
    "DEF" : {
                "values": {
                    "ups": {
                        "data": {
                            "1574065955000": 0.01,
                            "1574066955000": 0.09
                        }
                    },
                    "cpu": {
                        "data": {
                            "1574065955000": 0.09,
                            "1574066955000": 0.04,
                            "1574067955000": 0.0,
                            "1574068955000": 0.001
                        }
                    }
                }
    },
    "scores_reference": {
        "low_deviations": "0.0 - 0.4",
        "moderate_deviations": "0.4 - 0.7",
        "high_deviations": "0.7 - 1.0"
    }
}
```

Can someone please suggest how can I create the pojos ? I tried multiple things but is not working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any online JSON to POJO converter links and paste you sample JSON to get the corresponding POJO. following are some of the links :

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

https://www.freecodeformat.com/json2pojo.php

Comment: Thanks, but this would create classes for all the dynamic objects which is not correct. here "ABC" and "DEF" are dynamic .